# Is there a way to scrape strings in between 2 patterns using sed or grep?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract strings between 2 patter for each line of my log file

For example

```
some_string: stuff_i_am_interested_in some_other_string
some_string: stuff_i_am_interested_in some_other_string
some_string: stuff_i_am_interested_in some_other_string
some_string: stuff_i_am_interested_in some_other_string
```

Is there a way to get `stuff_i_am_interested_in` ?

Comment: Welcome to U/L. What have you tried?

Comment: It would be better if your provided some actual lines of your log file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 file
stuff_i_am_interested_in
stuff_i_am_interested_in
stuff_i_am_interested_in
stuff_i_am_interested_in
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'some_string: \K.*(?= some_other_string)' file
grep -Po '(?<=some_string: ).*(?= some_other_string)' file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/some_string: \(.*\) some_other_string/\1/p' file
```

If `some_string` is not at the beginning of the line and `some_other_string` is not at the end of the line, you can do:

```
sed -n 's/.*some_string: \(.*\) some_other_string.*/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with sed:

`cat logfile | sed -n -e 's/some_string: //p' | sed -n -e 's/ some_other_string//p'`

Comment: `cat` isn't necessary nor is calling `sed` twice.